# Android JNI/JAVA mixed debug using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, java-native-interface, native

I have a library project containing native C code. I can successfully call the native code
from the application project by adding it as a referenced library, but I can not debug the native code.
I added the following to the library's Application.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -g
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

And compiled with : `ndk-build NDK_DEBUG=1`

My question is how can I force the eclipse to stop execution on a breakpoint?
Where could I configure the gdb to start with my application?

Thank you,

Daniel

Comment: I know this is not exactly what you are looking for, but for quick and dirty debugging of native code, I prefer pure gdb: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/locking-jdb-gdb-together-michal-konrad-owsiak